# Detecting click in jQuery for a CSS class

Tags: html, jquery

I have the following code in my HTML file.

In the JavaScript file I am trying to detect a click on any item which has the class `dropdown-item ml-2` associated with it. However, the `click()` function is not getting caught.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-item ml-2').click(function() {
    alert('hello');
  });
});
```

```html
<span class="dropdown-item-text font-weight-bold">People</span>
<a class="dropdown-item ml-2" id="optAffiliates" href="#">Affiliates</a>
<a class="dropdown-item ml-2" id="optBusiness" href="#">Business</a>
<a class="dropdown-item ml-2" href="#">Inquiries</a>
<a class="dropdown-item ml-2" href="#">Students</a>
<a class="dropdown-item ml-2" href="#">Students</a>
</span>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js">
</script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="{{url('myproject/public/js/ya-jquery.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid and it looks like you are loading jQuery TWICE

Comment: i just copied the relevant part from the html file. Please let me know if i need top copy the entire file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.dropdown-item ml-2')
```

would select `<ml-2>` **elements** inside other elements that have a css class of `dropdown-item`. Your code has no `<ml-2>` elements, instead `ml-2` exists as an additional css class.

What you want instead:

```
$('.dropdown-item.ml-2')
```

If you want to select items that have more than one specific css class, you write them without any spaces in between and just connect them with the class selector `.`

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is missing a `.` before `ml-2` and it should be

```
$('.dropdown-item.ml-2')
```